# Updating kernel: vmlinuz in /boot not being created by DNF

Tags: fedora, kernel, upgrade, dnf

Brand new `F23` install, trying to update the kernel. I did lose power during the first round of `dnf update` and have to go clear out a bunch of conflicts that dnf kept reporting. It's possible I removed something that's needed, to be totally honest here.

Anyways, I've tried both `dnf update` and `dnf install kernel` (after `dnf remove kernel`). They install the latest kernel to `/lib/modules/4.4.9-300.fc23.x86_64/`, but no new `vmlinuz` files end up in `/boot`, so `grub2-mkconfig` won't find it and use it.

Any suggestions as to where I could start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up updating to the F24 beta, as it's being frozen anyways. This fixed the problem, and I'm now running on the 4.7 kernel.

Answer (score 1):

```
dnf reinstall kernel-core
```

vmlinuz file is provided by kernel-core package so you will need to reinstall it

source https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?310114-Updating-kernel-vmlinuz-in-boot-not-being-created-by-DNF

Answer (score 1):

ensure `/etc/machine-id` exist and is valid/not empty

```
test -s /etc/machine-id
```

instead "kernel-install" command will not provide kernel below `/boot`

- from systemd package
- called in kernel-core rpm post-install script (`rpm -qp --scripts kernel-core-*.rpm`)

reinstall kernel-core package then

```
dnf reinstall kernel-core
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
dnf reinstall kernel
```

or (better)

```
dnf reinstall kernel-4.4.9-300
```

since it's possible that `dnf` has status saying that the given set of files is complete.

Comment: Tried both, it's still not putting a vmlinuz/initramfs/config/System.map file in /boot

Comment: I did just notice that when dnf lists the kernel package, arch, version, etc upon running dnf install kernel...the size is 58k. Normal?

Comment: That's too small (the kernel is several Mb).  Your `/boot` may be short of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

**CentOS/RHEL** - I had a similar issue to this:

If you're attempting to build a virtual machine from a clean state the file `/etc/machine-id` must be present as mentioned above.

Mine was empty and reinstalling kernel and kernel-core packages will do nothing until that file is populated with a value. To generate a usable machine-id use:

```bsh
uuidgen > /etc/machine-id
yum reinstall kernel*
```